# AngularJS app with ASP MVC - getting rid of hasbang with URL rewrite/routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have kind of a mixed application with Angular and ASP.NET MVC.
It works this way:

1. User enters `example.com`, MVC controller checks if he is `Authorized`:

   - if he is, controller returns view `Main` which contains Angular app.
   - if he isn't, then a view `Index` is shown, with login/register form
2. Logging in/ registering is done within `Account` controller at `example.com/Account`
3. Angular app has `html5Mode` enabled, so inside-app routing is like `example.com/home`,`example.com/profile` etc.

I've tried messing aroung with MVC's `RouteConfig`, as well as simple rewriting

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest( Object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    string url = Request.Url.LocalPath;
    if ( !System.IO.File.Exists( Context.Server.MapPath( url ) ) )
        Context.RewritePath( ROOT_DOCUMENT );
}
```

source: [ui-router GitHub page](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)

But nothing adresses my situtation.
Above code basically disables whole MVC routing, so I can't access `/Account/LogIn`

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar issue. I think the best answer I can come up with is to define specialized routes that will allow access to the controllers, and then define a DefaultAll route that will default to the specific controller, and action method that has my Angular code.
For example in my case I have one controller Page, and my first route is

```
routes.MapRoute(
              name: "Default",
              url: "Page/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Main", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
```

This means any request with Page/ - will route appropriately to the controller, and use the action method defined in the request. For example Page/main, Page/one, Page/two

My second request is a catch all that defaults to the controller Page, action method Main.

```
routes.MapRoute(
             name: "DefaultAll",
             url: "{*.}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Main", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
```

This means when I paste a url like http://localhost/myapp/persons , it will load the Page controller, Main action method, which has my Angular routes defined and then Angular will parse the persons part of the URL to perform its routing.

This does mean that if you have more controller, you will need a specialized route for each one.

If you have come up with a better way please do let me know.